# Scanner class throwing java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-----WELCOME-----");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER TOTAL PERSON COUNT: ");
        long c = input.nextLong();

    }
}
```

Comment: How about reading the exception first? `Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

Comment: What input are you trying to enter?

Comment: It is perfectly working fine with integers

Comment: m giving input as 9.876

Comment: You can't format a number and expect the scanner to understand the formatting. Input 9876 instead or use double/float instead if that is what you meant.

Comment: @MayankRana you should go for `Float`

Comment: @MayankRana your input is decimal , but your `c` is `long` that is why you are getting the error. type of your input should match type of `c`

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Main{ public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-----WELCOME-----");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER TOTAL PERSON COUNT: ");
        int c = input.nextInt();
        long[] income= new long[c+1];
        for(int i=0;i<=c;i++){
             System.out.println("enter income");
             income[i] = input.nextLong();
             System.out.println(income[i]);
        }
    }
       }

Comment: this is my actual program

Comment: tried giving input as 97865

Comment: still showing same error

Answer (score 0):

actually the exception `java.util.InputMismatchException` is self-explanatory, it is reporting input mismatch, the input you gave is mismatching with the variable type it is assigned to.

based on your comments: the following line of code is expecting `long` (possibly `int`due to numeric promotion)input because type of `c` is `long`, so you should input `long`  or `int`

```
long c = input.nextLong();
```

if you want to capture decimal input, match type of the input with variable `c`

```
double c = input.nextDouble();
```